# DDL - can't use delimiter?

Tags: propel

I'm trying to create some database triggers post database created, by adding them to a sql file that is called from sqldb.map.

However, to create triggers, I need to use the delimiter command to change the delimiter to something besides the semi-colon. This fails, and the result trigger creation fails, both with the standard, `you have a syntax error message.`. I can run a simple sql statement this way, but it doesn't like delimiter.

Any thoughts?

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER `SHOW_ADD_NEWS_ITEM` 
AFTER INSERT ON `show`
FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        declare username varchar(255);
        IF NEW.privacy_key IS NOT NULL AND NEW.privacy_key <> 'PRIVATE' and (NOT EXISTS (select id from feed_friend_activity 
                where location_identifier = NEW.uuid and user_id = NEW.user_id and event_type = 'published show')) THEN
            select concat(user.first_name,user.last_name) into username from user where user.id = NEW.user_id;
            insert into feed_friend_activity 
                (location_identifier,user_id,event_type,user_name,item_name,created_on) 
                values (NEW.uuid,NEW.user_id,'published show',username,NEW.name,NEW.created_on);
        END IF;
    END
//
```

Answer (score 1):

Propel 1.6.7 now supports `DELIMITER`. See [this Pull Request](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/pull/381) for more information. If your SQL is valid, then it will work fine with 1.6.7 or upper.